# How to make bottom of browser scroll to bottom of div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to generate this effect that when you click a button, the page will scroll to a div and align the bottom of the browser with the bottom of the div. I'v been messing around with scrollTop() and offset() but haven't gotten it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: what code do you have currently?

Comment: I have all the divs placed and all the onclick events set up, all I need is the actual scrolling part.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code

```
var wHeight = $(window).height(); // Height of view port
var eOffset = $('#elementID').offset().top; // Y-offset of element
var eHeight = $('#elementID').height(); // Height of element

$(window).scrollTop(eOffset - wHeight + eHeight); // See below for explanation
```

**Explanation**

1. You set the `.scrollTop()` as the y-offset of the element which places the element at the top of the window
2. You then subtract the height of the view port which puts the element off of the screen (just below)
3. You then add the height of the element to align the bottom of the view port with the bottom of the browser

Comment: It wasn't working quite right when I resized the screen, I changed it to scrollTop(eOffset - wHeight) to make sure it moved the screen to right above the element but it was several spaces to far up.

Comment: But you did manage to get it to work as you wanted? If not, can you link to the site?

Comment: No it was not working, I changed the arguments to experiment with it and it didn't behave as expected. And I'm working on the site locally so can't share it :/

Comment: What about creating a jsfiddle? Just to clarify.... If you use `(eOffset)` it should place it at the top of the browser window. If you use `(eOffset - wHeight)` it should place just off of the bottom. If you use `(eOffset - wHeight + eHeight)` it should place aligned with the bottom.

Comment: You might also try using the _inspect_ element option in your browser to see where the borders etc of the element are

Comment: Yes I understand the parameters and I inspected the element margins/paddings etc to make sure they weren't growing as I resized the screen. When I make the screen smaller is when it's not working.

Comment: Yes, I assumed you did, but thought best to check! It's supposed to scroll when you click a button? Do you calculate the `wHeight` (window height) when the button is pressed? or is that calculated on load of the page? Try refreshing the page with the screen at a smaller size and then testing

Comment: Tried it to no avail :(. And I would think theoretically it shouldn't matter if the browser was resized without refreshing or loaded at the 'smaller' size.

Comment: Well, that depends on when you calculate `wHeight` if you only calculate it once when the page loads originally in _full size_ then it will still be trying to use that value when it's been resized...

Comment: Can you test this: http://jsfiddle.net/QLHkp/1/ to see if you get the same problem?

Comment: You click on the boxes to make it scroll!

Comment: Ahhh I figured it out, I had a problem with some of my divs that were floated which accounted for the discrepancy in distance jumped. Now it works perfectly :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
     }, 2000);
 });
```

taken from http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/

Comment: I think that will make the top of the browser scroll to the top of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.scrollHeight:`

```
$("#div1").animate({ scrollTop: $("#div1").scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

**EDITED**

That's because you have to calculate the height etc

```
var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
```